# Matching multiple variables in different dataframes and return value in R

Tags: r, if-statement, matching

I have two data frames:

```
c1 <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2")
d1 <- c("2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2021")

dfx <- data.frame(c1,d1)
```

```
c2 <- c("1", "1", "2")
ds <- c("2017", "2020", "2017")
de <- c("2018", "2021", "2018")

dfy <- data.frame(c2,ds,de)
```

c1 and c2 are unique IDs and d1, ds, and de are dates. ds and de are start and end dates.

I'm looking for a way to identify if the dates in dfx overlaps within the duration (ds and de) in dfy. I want to do this by id. And if they overlap, return a value of 0 and if it doesn't, return value of 1 in dataframe dfy.

So, ideal output of dfy should be:

| c2 | ds | de | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017 | 2018 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020 | 2021 | 0 |
| 2 | 2017 | 2018 | 1 |

Any help will be appreciated! Especially if using dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

```
# set as data.table
lapply(list(dfx, dfy), \(i) setDT(i))

# join
dfz <- dfx[dfy, on=.(c1=c2), allow.cartesian=T]

# flag if overlap
dfz[, output := 1
    ][ d1 >= ds
       & d1 <= de
       , output := 0
       ]

# aggregate
dfz <- dfz[, .(output = min(output)), .(c1, ds, de)]
dfz
   c1   ds   de output
1:  1 2017 2018      0
2:  1 2020 2021      0
3:  2 2017 2018      1
```